# Creating ssh for local ftp server

Tags: ssh, ftp

I have recently satup a ftp server for a friend of mine, he has a akasa air duodck witch would not connect to the local wifi. I took a look in the modem and found a application. With this application you can connect a harddrive to the modem and setup a ftp server.

Now we discoverd that everytime we want to open a file it only opens it in a browser and it wont open with the program we would normaly use.

I was thinking about setting up a ssh and hoping that would fix the problem.

So actually im looking for advise on one of these three questions.

Is it possible to open an image from the ftp with photo viewer.
Is there another way to look into images from an ftp.
Is it possible to setup a ssh for a local server and how can i accomplish this.

Or should i look into samba

Thanks in advance and please let me know if this question is more suitable somewhere else.